# How to convert html into javascript string using gulp task?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

**Input**

```
<div id="main">
   <div>
   Sample Html
   </div>
</div>
```

**Output**

```
  var myvar = '<div id="main">'+
    '   <div>'+
    '   Sample Html'+
    '   </div>'+
    '</div>';
```

I want to convert html template and add the output into the angular directive in template part.

Comment: I need to add html template into directive template part. For this I want to generate a javascript string from html so I can add/replace it into directive template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @dfsq suggests you need the [html2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html2js) plugin:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var html2js = require('gulp-html2js');
gulp.task("createTemplates", function(){
    //create js templates for templatecache
    return gulp.src([baseDirectory + "/your_template_dir/*.tpl.html"])
        .pipe(html2js("directive.templates.js", {
            base: baseDirectory,
            name: "my.templates" //module name for injector
        })).pipe(gulp.dest("your_output_directory"));
});
```

creates:

```
(function(module) {
    try { app = angular.module("my.templates"); }
    catch(err) { app = angular.module("my.templates", []); }
    app.run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
        "use strict";

        $templateCache.put("your_template_dir/template.tpl.html","<p>Template content</p>");
    });
});
```

Now you can inject the module ("my.templates") into your directive and use "your_template_dir/template.tpl.html" as your templateUrl.

Comment: Hi appreciated for reply, but I don't want to create another module for template and inject into my directive. 
firstly I  wants to inject my template as string in directive like { `template'<div id="main">'+
  ' <div>'+
  ' Sample Html'+
  ' </div>'+
  '</div>';}`
and second is even I change any thing in my template it reflect into my directory template as well. I already done second part using gulp-replace.But I am stuck in first part. I tried first part as well to read html file remove line-breaks put into template using replace some string. But the things is code is not formatted.

Comment: Why would you want that the code is formatted? If you minify/uglify the files (what you should do, to decrease network traffic) the formatting is lost anyway.